# How to display image from aws s3 in blade laravel 5.2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have created a method for getting the data(image file) from aws S3 like this :

```
 public static function getImage ($imagePath)
    {
        if(Storage::exists($imagePath))
        {
            return Storage::disk('s3')->get($imagePath);
        }else
        {
            return 'No Image';
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that those image is exist on the aws, so there is no problem with that.
And then I use above method as the src in my blade view like this :

```
{!!Html::image(getImage($myPath),'logo',['width'=>60,'height'=>55])!!}
```

$myPath here already point to the specific file on aws for example : bucket/file.jgp. But when I run my webpage, this Html::Image gives a view like this :
[image]

What's going on here ? Why Html::image can't render my image file ? :(

Comment: just `{{ HTML::image($myPath) }}`

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/185/generating-an-html-image-element

Comment: If I use just HTML::image($myPath), it gives an empty image... :)

Comment: `return Storage::disk('s3')->get($imagePath);` returns a raw string content of an image

Comment: `HTML::image` doesn't seem like it would support `raw`

Comment: mmmm........ How to view it then in blade Mr. Scottevans...?? :)

Comment: Could you do `var_dump(Storage::disk('s3')->get($imagePath));` inside your `getImage()` function so i can see the exact format

Comment: var_dump gives me a string(42896) "bla bla bla Mr. Scottevans...

Comment: Try @Skysplit solution below

Comment: Storage::url is undefined for me... I could'nt use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{!!Html::image(<Your S3 bucket URL>.$myPath),'logo',['width'=>60,'height'=>55])!!}
```

You can save the S3 URL in a config file and use the config value instead of writing actual value everytime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vikas... It seems that I have a bucket permission issues here.. :v

Comment: You should also set visibility when storing the images to S3 `Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.jpg', $contents, 'public');` . [File Visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#file-visibility)

Comment: Oooowh... I seee... Okiee... Lemme put 'public' then... :D

Comment: mmm... it's same.... Still having a permission issue after putting 'public'... :'(

Comment: Not sure what's the issue then

Comment: I think your answer is right @Vikas... :)
I checked another bucket aand seems you are right... Cooool...

Comment: All these people have no idea about S3 permission, Always assuming all files in the internet are public. pooh!

Answer (score 8):

Works on Laravel 6.x

```
<img src="{{Storage::disk('s3')->url($imagePath)}}">
```

Comment: This is only working if setVisiblity is public

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Storage::url($imagePath)`. Please see [Filesystem / Cloud storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#retrieving-files) on laravel docs

Comment: That isn't correct. `Storage::disk()->get()` will return a raw image content string.

Comment: Storage::url is undefined... I can't use that, so I'm using Storage::disk()->get instead.. :)

Comment: `Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath)` should be available. Then displaying image would only require setting image `src` tag to this method's result

Answer (score 2):

I think that private visibility of images is an important security feature.
I found a solution :-)

**Method in Controller**:

```
/**
* @param string $name : image name on bucket 
* ( stored if you want into database ) 
*/

public function show( $name ) {
    
   $path = config('filesystems.disks.s3.base_directory') . '/' . $name;
   $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $data = Storage::get( $path );
   $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode( $data );
            
   return view( 'show', [ 'src' => $base64 ]);        
}
```

**The view:**

...

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Laravel File Retrive with Amazon S3 </h2></div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    **<img src="{{ $src }}"/>**

  </div>
</div>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This code snippet solved it

```
<img src="{!! url(<path to your image>) !!}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to give it public promotion in the controller

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('profileImages/', $request->file('profile_image'), 'public');

//save image name in database
$user->profile_image = basename($path);
```

In blade file

```
<img src="{{Storage::disk('s3')->url('profileImages/' . $user->profile_image)}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an accessor like follow to get Image URL

It returns URL to the image and you can access it by $profile->image

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {

        return Storage::disk('s3')->url($value);
    }

    return "https://source.unsplash.com/96x96/daily";
}
```

I assume you save image as follow

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 's3');
        
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

$profile->update([
      'image' =>  $path
      ]);
```

You can check this commit for more detail

https://github.com/itxshakil/ediary/commit/23cb4b1cb7b8a4eac68f534e8c5b6897abc6421a

Comment: Is that your repo? Im wondering why you set the return, in the Model, to be a url, how should I type it in the blade view if in my case im storing to S3 but im trying to return "image_url" from the "posts" table? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes @Eduardo , It's my repo.  I return because it is an accessor. Now In blade, I can show the image by `<img src="{{$model->image}}" >`

Answer (score 1):

I have read every solution and no one has pointed it directly. So I thought to write my answers. For this problem I just required to add this simple line and boom, it starts working. But I got access denied alert you should check that problem too.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{!! Storage::disk('s3')->url('thumbs/' . $business->image->path) !!}" alt="thumb">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works
`Storage::disk('s3')->url($imagePath)`

and also from your Minio Browser.

[image]
[image]

You have to `Add` a policy to `Read and Write`